# Firebase Dynamic link doesn't work correctly on IOS 15+

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, safari, firebase-dynamic-links

I need your help.

---

Dynamic link does not work correctly on iOS 15+. The application opens but the link is not transmitted.
Firebase version **8.8.0**,
Unity version **2020.3.3 LTS**,
**Associated domains** are written as it should be.
On older versions of IOS, everything works as expected.
On Android, too, everything is fine.

---

I noticed that the **preview page** does not open on iOS 15+ and immediately after answering the question - do I want to open my application , it opens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. It was just necessary to use the percent encoding the link.